# Syntax to transform the scale of a UIImageView in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of UIImageViews and I am attempting to transform their scale, how I cannot seem to nail down the call correctly.

Here is what I have tried:

```
[[self.Images objectAtIndex:kGeneral] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f)];

[[self.Images objectAtIndex:kGeneral] transform] = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
```

I seem to be missing something simple. In any event, the compile time error I receive is:

```
Multiple methods 'setTransform:' found with mismatched results, parameter type or attributes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### tl; dr

```
[(UIImageView*)self.Images[kGeneral] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f)];
```

Also, **please**, don't use capitalized names for properties/variables. Change `Images` to `images`.

---

#### Explanation

The `setTransform:` method exists in several classes with different signatures. For instance `CALayer` has a `transform` property as well, but it is of `CATransform3D` type.

`objectAtIndex:` returns an object of type `id`, so the compiler cannot decide which `setTransform:` you are referring to.

Adding an explicit cast disambiguates the type, making the compiler happy.

Bottom line, as you notice, I'm using the modern array access syntax, which changes nothing in practical terms, but it makes the code more pleasant to read.

Comment: well it wasn't that obvious ;) I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Yea, I get that capitalized property name from where I work..they set backing instance variables like so: _images, and then the property as Images. It's annoying but now it's almost instinct lol

Comment: `_images` for the backing ivar is appropriate and very idiomatic. Capitalized names for properties are not. I'd consider quitting the job (ok maybe a little too dramatic)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [self.Images objectAtIndex:kGeneral];
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
((UIImageView *)[self.Images objectAtIndex:kGeneral]).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
```

you have to cast your object in array to UIImageView to compiler know on which kind of object he should looks for property 'transform'.